# Why do I get 502 when I reload my Nodejs Server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, pm2

I'm using NGINX with reverse proxy to a cluster of node process which are managed by PM2.
Sometimes when I do `pm2 reload app` I get a 502 bad gateway thrown by nginx for a complete minute or two and sometimes not.

Why is that? When monitoring the logs the server gets up again quickly, shows the database connected log as well. But nginx throws 502.

What might be the culprit?

---

Edit: Added NGINX config.

```
server {
        root /home/xx;
        listen 80;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name localhost xx.com;

        location ~* \.(pdf|css|html|js)$ {
           expires 2d;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
                expires 365d;
        }

        location /images
        {
                alias /home/xx/images;
        }

        location /web/public/assets/fonts
        {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                alias /home/xx/web/public/assets/fonts;
        }

        location /web/public
        {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                alias /home/xx/web/public;
        }

        location /public
        {
                alias /home/xx/public;
        }

        location /uploads
        {
                alias home/xx/uploads;
        }


        location / {

                proxy_pass http://nodes;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

upstream nodes {
        ip_hash;
        server 127.0.0.1:3030;
        server 127.0.0.1:3031;
        server 127.0.0.1:3032;
        server 127.0.0.1:3033;
}

server {

    if ($host = xx.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name xx.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: You may want to check the pm2 logs after reloading the app. 502 is generally thrown by nginx when proxy server (your node app) gives an invalid response..

Comment: no such error in pm2 logs

Comment: try to check nginx logs at /var/log/nginx/error.log unless you have updated the location..

Comment: I did `tail -30 /var/log/nginx/error.log`. There are a lot of `connect() failed (111: Connection refused)` in that log.

Comment: Are you trying to run multiple node instances on the same port by any chance?

Comment: No, I'm not. And it gets okay after a minute or so. So why the timeout?

Also those errors are due to HTTP/2 I suppose. Here's the complete error:
``` *27286717 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 152.31.12.93, server: 69.183.92.12, request: "GET /profile HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3032/profile", host: "xx.com" ```

Comment: Please share your nginx conf. Are you using ```localhost``` in the server block?

Comment: Added nginx config @d_bhatnagar

Comment: Try changing ```localhost``` in your ```server name``` with 127.0.0.1 and ```listen 0.0.0.0:80```?

Comment: Okay so I don't know why I had mentioned `localhost` in the `server name`, and now I have removed it altogether.

Comment: Is the original issue fixed?

Comment: Sorry forgot to update you on it, no it has not made any difference. I'll do more testing today and update here